# Optimize index on my table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I've a table *friends* :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
    `fr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fr_sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `fr_receiver` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `fr_validate` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`fr_id`),
    KEY `fr_sender` (`fr_sender`),
    KEY `fr_receiver` (`fr_receiver`),
    KEY `fr_validate` (`fr_validate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2397953 ;

fr_id       => index
fr_sender   => sender of the friend request
fr_receiver => the receiver
fr_falidate => 0 = no reply, 1 = request accepted, 2 = request refused.
```

My mysql-slow.log have many lines for this query:

```
SELECT fr_id FROM friends WHERE (fr_sender = '113405' OR fr_receiver = '113405') && fr_validate = "1";
# Query_time: 5.607869  Lock_time: 0.000052 Rows_sent: 106  Rows_examined: 833517
```

How can I optimise my index for this query ?

Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to consider (LIST partitioning on column fr_validate) partitioning if your MySQL server version supports it.. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html..

Comment: And why you do use fr_sender = '113405' when it should be fr_sender = 113405 ?? fr_sender is an int type... this can also be the reason why MySQL cant use an index.

Comment: it's a copy/paste from my log. Obviously in my code there is no quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to optimize when you use `OR` between conditions for two *different* columns. It often results in a costly table-scan.

Here's a workaround:

```
ALTER TABLE friends 
 ADD INDEX (fr_validate, fr_sender),
 ADD INDEX (fr_validate, fr_receiver);

SELECT fr_id FROM friends WHERE fr_validate = '1' AND fr_sender = '113405'
UNION 
SELECT fr_id FROM friends WHERE fr_validate = '1' AND fr_receiver = '113405'
```

The reason to create two indexes is so that each subquery has a respective index to minimize the rows examined as much as possible. Then the results from each subquery are combined, which gives an equivalent result set as your original query.

PS: Please use single-quotes for string literals and date literals. MySQL allows double-quotes to serve the same role by default, but if you use another RDBMS brand, or if you `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES` in MySQL, you'll find the standard meaning of double-quotes is for delimiting table names and column names, not strings.